# Consume JMS queue with a C# client

Tags: c#, jms

I have details of a JMS queue i.e. host, port, topicName. Is there an easy way I can consume messages from this queue without recourse to using Java .jars etc?

Answer (score 3):

You have not mentioned the name of the JMS provider where the JMS queue is hosted. Most of the JMS providers provide a C# API for sending/receiving messages to/from JMS queue. For example if your JMS provider is IBM WebSphere MQ, then you have XMS .NET(which is JMS specification implementation in C#) and native C# API.

The bottom line: Look at the documentation of your JMS provider for C# APIs.